# How to check two arrays in one foreach loop?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How do I check if any of the keys in foreach loop exists in another array's value ?

Array 1 I want to check

```
$array1 = array(
    'a' => '1',
    'b' => '2',
    'c' => '3',
);
```

And the Array 2 which Array 1 should be compared to

```
$reserved_words = array('b');
```

What I want is to check whether the conditional check is TRUE to apply specific actions. My code looks like this now:

```
foreach( $array1 as $key => $value )
{
    // Check for reserved words
    if( in_array($key, $reserved_words)
    {
        // Some action
    }

    // Code...
}
```

I can't find anything similiar to `array_key_exists`, probably I am missing something.

I want to check it by simply doing this:

```
if( array_value_exists($value, $reserved_words) )
```

But the problem is that no `array_value_exists` function is available.

Comment: Aside from missing the `as` keyword, what's the problem?

Comment: Hi there, I think you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php from what you describe. No need for a foreach loop even?

Comment: sorry for errors, i was typing it on mobile phone.
anything similiar to `array_key_exists` but for checking the values instead the keys ?

Comment: @Fluffeh - it's good but not exactly what I need in my case. I need to check if value `some string` exists in `$someArray`. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot first the `as` keyword in your foreach header and you missed a `)` in your if statement.

So this should work:

```
<?php

    $array1 = array(
                'a' => '1',
                'b' => '2',
                'c' => '3',
            );

    $reserved_words = array('b');

    foreach( $array1 as $key => $value ) {
                   //^^Here 'as' keyword

        if( in_array($key, $reserved_words)) {
            echo $key;                   //^Here ')' closed if statement
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: I did the same, but `in_array` did not worked for me, I had exactly the same checking. Will recheck it again, I misstyped something I guess.

Comment: @aspirinemaga Copy the entire code from my answer. it should work! you should get the output 'b'

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array(
  'a' => '1',
  'b' => '2',
  'c' => '3',
);
$reserved_words = array('b');
>>> array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($reserved_words));
=> [
     "b" => "2"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the 'as' keyword. Please put the code like below

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $val){
if(in_array($key, $reserved_words)){
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

}